# Why didn't they create a media sensation about the K-Pax Alien?

Tags: plot-explanation, k-pax

In *K-Pax* the alien even impressed astrophysicists at the planetarium by drawing its planet's orbits.

The alien was always restricted to a mental institution.

Why didn't they create a media sensation about the K-Pax Alien?

Comment: Because noone actually believed him? Despite his astronomic abilities the film is still *highly* ambiguous about Prot being an alien or not.

Comment: It's never made clear whether he's an alien.  He could just be a high-functioning autistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were many contradictions in Prot's character -- on one hand, he had an astonishing knowledge of astronomy (some of the things he'd discovered were absolutely new to some famous astronomers); on the other hand, he was hospitalized in a mental institute due to the fact that he had many mental issues. The staff obviously concluded that they were dealing with a mentally insane genius. 
He was maybe quite a unique and non-standard patient, but regardless - he was **a patient in a mental hospital**.

Some people took this pretty seriously, and investigated his story, but you must remember that the entire situation ended pretty quickly -- throughout the entire film, they had very little time.

Prot had a "deadline" -- if it was a countdown to a return to his home-planet or to a complete mental breakdown, either way it was a real deadline.